# How do I accomplish "cascading grouping" of columns in ANSI SQL?

Tags: sql, string, count, presto

I have a Presto SQL table that looks something like this:

```
|tenant|type|environment                                    |
|                                                           |
| X    | A  |http:a.b.c(foo)/http:a.b.c(bar)/http:a.b.c(baz)|
| X    | A  |http:d.e.f(foo)/http:d.e.f(bar)/http:d.e.f(baz)|
| X    | A  |http:g.h.i(foo)                                |
| X    | B  |http:g.h.i(foo)/http:g.h.i(bar)                |
```

All columns are of type **string**.
I need to produce output that counts each environment type (foo, bar, or baz) per tenant and type. I.e. the above data should be listed somewhat like this:

```
X A foo 3
    bar 2
    baz 2
X B foo 1
    bar 1
```

I've been trying queries like this:

```
SELECT "tenant_id", "type_id", "environment", count(*) AS total_count 
FROM "tenant_table"    
WHERE "environment" LIKE '%foo%' 
GROUP BY "tenant_id", "type_id", "environment";
```

But I'm not getting the output I need. I do have a little bit of flexibility of changing the data types. The data comes from a CSV file originally. For example, if it makes things easier to redefine the type of the "environment" column to something like an array, that is an option. Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's a fixed list of values, with at most 1 occurance per string, the, you can put it in a derived table and use `like` to search for matches:

```
select t.tenant, t.type, v.val, count(*) cnt
from tenant_db t
inner join (values ('foo'), ('bar'), ('baz')) v(val)
    on t.environment like '%' || v.val || '%'
group by t.tenant, t.type, v.val
```

Depending on your requirement, you might want to narrow the search criteria in order to avoid fake positives; maybe using the parentheses:

```
on t.environment like '%(' || v.val || ')%'
```

Or using a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the values with [`regexp_extract_all`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html?highlight=regexp_extract#regexp_extract_all) and use [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html?highlight=unnest#unnest) to "flatten" the resulting arrays before computing the aggregation:

```sql
WITH data(tenant, type, environment) AS (
    VALUES
        ('X', 'A', 'http:a.b.c(foo)/http:a.b.c(bar)/http:a.b.c(baz)'),
        ('X', 'A', 'http:d.e.f(foo)/http:d.e.f(bar)/http:d.e.f(baz)'),
        ('X', 'A', 'http:g.h.i(foo)'),
        ('X', 'B', 'http:g.h.i(foo)/http:g.h.i(bar)')
)
SELECT tenant, type, value, count(*)
FROM data, UNNEST(regexp_extract_all(data.environment, '\(([^\)]+)\)', 1)) t(value)
GROUP BY tenant, type, value
```

produces:

```
 tenant | type | value | _col3
--------+------+-------+-------
 X      | A    | baz   |     2
 X      | A    | bar   |     2
 X      | A    | foo   |     3
 X      | B    | bar   |     1
 X      | B    | foo   |     1
```